# Compile time C++ checksum

Tags: c++

Есть структура:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct protocol_header {
    uint32_t sign = 42;
    uint8_t checksum = 0;
    uint8_t length = 6;

    constexpr protocol_header(void) {
        checksum += sign & 0xFF000000 >> 24;
        checksum += sign & 0x00FF0000 >> 16;
        checksum += sign & 0x0000FF00 >> 8;
        checksum += sign & 0x000000FF >> 0;    

        m_checksum += length;

        m_checksum = 0x100 - m_checksum;
    }
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

и объявление может быть таким. Главное чтобы заголовок попал в нужную секцию!

```
__attribute__((section(".protocol_header_section"))
static protocol_header;
```

Требуется во время компиляции занести в поле checksum побайтовую сумму этой структуры.

"Плохое" решение приведено.

Размер реальной структуры больше. Поэтому складывать байты вручную не получится.

Comment: Мне кажется, в первых трех строках вычисления checksum Вы потеряли концевые нули.  Должно быть вот так: checksum += sign & 0xFF000000 >> 24; если я правильно понимаю ,что Вы делаете

Comment: Да, возможно код и не рабочий, но мысльто ясна правда

Comment: Имена полей важны, или важно просто сформировать нужную последовательность байтов в секции?

Comment: структура ложится в секцию хорошо! нужно только просумировать байты с переполнением и запихать туда-же (в checksum)

Comment: Так чем вам ответы не нравятся? У вас уже 4 варианта решения в двух ответах. Вы редактируете вопрос просто что бы поднять наверх? Мне кажется что на ваш ответ уже ответили, поставьте зелёную галочку напротив ответа - тогда вопрос будет считаться отвеченным, либо отредактируйте вопрос так, что б было понятно почему вам варианты ниже не подходят.

Answer (score 0):

Если нужны вычисления именно при компиляции, то можно это сделать несколькими вариантами.

Через #define-макрос влоб (если структура одна)

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
#define protocol_header_sign 42
#define protocol_header_len 6
struct protocol_header { 
  uint32_t sign = protocol_header_sign ;
  uint8_t checksum = (protocol_header_sign  & 0xFF) +   protocol_header_len  /*+И так далее*/;
  uint8_t length = protocol_header_len;
};
 #pragma pack(pop)
```

Так же можно сделать шаблонный #define (`#define PROTOCOL_HEADER(SIGN,LEN) struct{...`) но шаблон template практичнее.

Второй способ - через шаблон, если структур две и более то подходит. Для структуры будет создано несколько "экземпляров", в отдельных случаях это полезно.

```
   #pragma pack(push, 1)
   template < uint32_t SIGN,uint8_t LEN> struct protocol_header  {
     uint32_t sign = SIGN;
     uint8_t checksum =  (SIGN & 0xFF) + LEN  /*+ и так далее*/;
     uint8_t length = LEN;
    };
   #pragma pack(pop)

   protocol_header<42,6> myprotocol1;
```

Только тогда в полях будут константные выражения, и расчёт будет сделан компилятором. Переменные в константые выражения подставлять нельзя (и в `protocol_header<42,6>` тоже нужно подставлять строго константы).

Ну и на десерт, вариант с пред-инициализацией структуры, в отдельных случаях подходит. Думаю это самый практичный вариант. В отличии от предыдущих двух - не будет плодится кучи копий класса. `protocol_header mystruct={ 42, выражение, 6  }`, что можно завернуть в #define макрос, который так же можно использовать повторно.

```
 #define init_protocol_header (SIGN,LEN) {SIGN,(SIGN & 0xFF) + LEN  /*+ и так далее*/, LEN }
 protocol_header  mystruct = init_protocol_header (42,6);
```

В итоге компилятор инициализирует переменную в mystruct, и либо будет использовать push/memcpy для инициализации в локальной области, либо забьет посчитанные константы в BSS, при обьявлении в глобальной области.

Comment: Друзья спасибо! Только хотелось избаться от ручного сложения. Со сложением руками мой вариант красивше не так-ли?

Answer (score 0):

Если имена полей нельзя терять, то самый простой вариант - добавить constexpr функции:

```
// предется вручную прописывать для всех используемых типов, кроме uint8_t ...
constexpr uint8_t  calc_hi(uint16_t i) { return static_cast<uint8_t >( (i>>8)  ); }
constexpr uint16_t calc_hi(uint32_t i) { return static_cast<uint16_t>( (i>>16) ); }
constexpr uint32_t calc_hi(uint64_t i) { return static_cast<uint32_t>( (i>>32) ); }

constexpr uint8_t  calc_low(uint16_t i) { return static_cast<uint8_t >( i ); }
constexpr uint16_t calc_low(uint32_t i) { return static_cast<uint16_t>( i ); }
constexpr uint32_t calc_low(uint64_t i) { return static_cast<uint32_t>( i ); }


constexpr uint8_t calc_checksumm(uint8_t  i) { return i; }
template<typename T>
constexpr uint8_t calc_checksumm(T i)
{
    return calc_checksumm( calc_hi(i) ) + calc_checksumm( calc_low(i) ) ;
}
template<typename A0, typename ... Args>
constexpr uint8_t calc_checksumm(A0 a0, Args...args)
{
    return calc_checksumm(a0)+calc_checksumm(args...);
}

template<typename T>
constexpr uint8_t calc_len(T ) { return sizeof(T); }

template<typename A0, typename ... Args>
constexpr uint8_t calc_len(A0 a0, Args...args)
{
    return calc_len(a0)+calc_len(args...);
}


struct protocol_header {
    uint32_t sign  = 42;
    uint64_t sign2 = 24;
    // Типы Важны! Но можно убрать списки в один define.
    uint8_t checksum = calc_checksumm((uint32_t) 42, uint64_t(24))
                      +calc_len      ((uint32_t) 42, uint64_t(24));
    uint8_t length   = calc_len      ((uint32_t) 42, uint64_t(24));
};
```

Здесь есть существенный недостаток - список типов и значений повторяется четыре раза. Можно слегка сгладить этот недостаток define-ами.

Comment: На сколько я помню в tuple не определен порядок полей, а это разумеется важно

Comment: Не определен, но я не встречал реализации где он был бы иным. В принципе, если идея понятна, можно переписать на array.